# Connectby with more than one root and dynamic

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have this table "con.cuenta"

[image]

I use `connectby` to obtain the levels:

```
SELECT t.cue_id, t.cue_id_ref, (t.level+1) nivel, t.branch 
FROM connectby('con.cuenta', 'cue_id', 'cue_id_ref', '1', 0,'/')
AS t(cue_id bigint, cue_id_ref bigint, level int,branch text)
```

[image]

The problem is that I have several roots and the connectby method works with a single root. Some alternative?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connectby` extension is pretty much obsolete since the introduction of [recursive CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) in Postgres 8.4

With a recursive CTE, it's simply to deal with multiple trees by using the correct WHERE clause for the non-recursive part:

```
with recursive tree as (
  select cue_id, 
         cue_id_ref, 
         1 as level, 
         cue_id::text as branch
  from "con.cuenta"
  where cue_id_ref is null
  union all
  select c.cue_id, 
         c.cue_id_ref, 
         p.level + 1, 
         concat(p.branch, '/', c.cue_id)
  from "con.cuenta" c
    join tree p on p.cue_id = c.cue_id_ref
)
select cue_id, cue_id_ref, level as nivel, branch
from tree;
```